# Bootstrap carousel item width cant be set to 100%

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5

I am making a slider with bootstrap carousel. I want 100% width slider. There is a gap between carousel inner and carousel item, when I set width to 100%. Carousel is not in a container div.

[image: the gap marked by red rectangle]

```css
.slide {
  width: 100%;
}

.slide,
.carousel-inner {
  height: 40rem;
  padding: 0px;
}

.carousel-item img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="MySlide" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#MySlide" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#MySlide" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#MySlide" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x200" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x200/ff0000" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x200/0000ff" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#MySlide" data-bs-slide="prev">
         <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#MySlide" data-bs-slide="next">
         <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: what is your parent class of carousel slide? Because your spacing depends on that

Comment: As you can see from the demo I created, the problem isn't with your slider. Show the rest of the page structure around it.

Answer (score -1):

Are you writing this carousel code inside container or container-fluid class? That adds left and right padding.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: It is not in a container div